# import "streamlit_webrtc" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, webrtc, streamlit, pylance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3ZJL.png)
Whenever I run my streamlit server on terminal "streamlit run app.py" I got that error shown on the pictures. Streamlit is working fine but streamlit_webrtc makes me in trouble.

I have tried every possible ways to solve this error like uninstall re-install Python, re-install streamlit,streamlit-webrtc. I have also created virtual private network to run this codes on several IDE but unable to fix that error.

Guys help me to out from this.

Comment: In  the message just follow what it says. Press the reportMissingImports.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [**DO NOT** post images of code or errors!!!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors?r=Saves_UserSavesList) Instead, use [properly-formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Do not share image of the code.